# Failing to detect long string character values

Tags: c, string, scanf, gets

I'm trying to detect how many occurrences of `D` and `T` are present in the string. Small string input is doing the job fine. But longer strings are returning garbage values.

```
int main() {
    int r = 0, x = 0, i = 0, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);
    char c[10];
    scanf("%s", &c);

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (c[i] == 'D')
            r++;
        if (c[i] == 'T')
            x++;
    }
    printf("%d\t", r);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: How long? Your variable is only big enough to hold 9 characters. If you type more, you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` causes undefined behaviour. The fflush function is only defined for output streams

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  this is not a valid statement.  Suggest: `int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}`

Comment: regarding; `char c[10];
    scanf("%s", &c);`  1) always check the returned value from `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario, any value returned, other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using the 'input format conversion specifier:  `%s`  and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d", &n); ...  char c[10];` Much better to use the Variable Length Array (VLA) feature of C.  There fore suggest:  `if( scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for length of array failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); } char c[n+1];`  +1 to allow for room for the trailing NUL byte

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {`  in C, the valid index into an array are 0...(number elements in array -1) so `i<=n` will result in indexing past the end of the array, which results in undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input buffer `c` is only large enough for a string of 9 characters. Any longer string input will cause undefined behavior, although it may take more than 10 for this undefined behavior to become noticeable to the user.

- Make the buffer larger and prevent buffer overflow with a numeric prefix int the `scanf` conversion specification.
- Note also that `fflush(stdin)` is not portable<sup>*</sup> at all, not should it be needed as the next `scanf()` will skip pending white space anyway.
- Note also that you should stop scanning the string when you reach the null terminator.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int r, x, i, n;
    char buf[256];

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && scanf("%255s", buf) == 1) {
        r = 0, x = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n && buf[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (c[i] == 'D')
                r++;
            if (c[i] == 'T')
                x++;
        }
        printf("%d\t%d\n", r, x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup>`fflush()` forces buffered output to be written to an output stream's associated file or device. `fflush()` has undefined behavior when called with a stream not open for output. Some systems define the behavior as to discard pending input, but the C Standard does not condone such behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I'm new...what does portable mean? what is the work of fflush?

Comment: `fflush()` forces buffered output to be written to an output stream's associated file or device. `fflush()` has undefined behavior when called with a stream not open for output. Some systems define the behavior as to discard pending input, but the C Standard does not condone such behavior, so compiling on different machines might produce unexpected behavior.

Comment: And "portable" here means that the program will work the same on  different machines and with different compilers.